# Is "I'm doing this primarily for myself, so..." proper English?

Tags: adjectives

Basically a quick question. Consider the phrase:

> *I'm doing this primarily for myself, so*...

I'm trying to almost literally translate a widely-used expression from my language to English, but it struck me as something a native English speaker wouldn't say (as well as most of my pathetic attempts, sadly).

Comment: I don't find anything wrong with the phrase, but it might sound a bit more natural in conversation if you changed _primarily_ to _mainly_, as in: _I'm doing this mainly for myself..._

Comment: @J.R. Agreed, *mainly* sounds more natural, & should be used in most situations. But I can think of at least one context in which *primarily* would be the definitive choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase you have in quotes in the title is totally proper, even common in the US. However, use the term, quickie, with caution. The term can have a meaning that's not really proper.